# Is offside called when a defender plays the puck into an attacker from a delayed offside?

Tags: rules, officiating, ice-hockey, nhl

Suppose a delayed offside is in effect, and a member of the defending team who gains control of the puck attempts to clear it. The puck inadvertently strikes an attacker when the attacker is still caught in the zone.

Is it called offside since the puck touched the attacker while he was in an offside position?

Answer (score 2):

This is covered by rule 83.3 from the [NHL Rulebook](http://www.nhl.com/nhl/en/v3/ext/rules/2017-2018-NHL-rulebook.pdf)

> [...] If, during the course of the delayed off-side, any member of the
>   attacking team **touches the puck**, attempts to gain possession of a
>   loose puck, forces the defending puck carrier further back into his
>   own zone, or who is about to make physical contact with the defending
>   puck carrier, the Linesman shall stop play for the off-side violation.

Even without any intent on the attacker, touching the puck in the zone appears to be sufficient to call the offside.